# Cloud SQL Proxy connection timesout occasionaly

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, cloud-sql-proxy

We use single-tenant architecture for our instances. Each instance contains 3 Django Apps i.e Django, Celery{worker, beat} and few other things that don't interact with the database. We deploy cloudsql-proxy as a sidecar for these django containers which are running as Pod in Google Kubernetes Engine. We are using CloudSQL (Postgres 9.6) by Google and it has Public IP address.

The problem is that we are getting Operational Errors on Django side i.e

```
OperationalError: server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
```

and when we check the Pod's logs at the same time when the OperationalError occurred we see the following log error from **cloudsql-proxy** container

```
couldn't connect to db_instance: dial tcp our_db_instance_public_ip:3307: connect: connection timed out
```

It is not that the connection to database doesn't work. It works most of the time but sometime it throws the above errors, which is kind of a pain because we run celery tasks every other minute and they fail due to this. Sometime, this occurs when the end user is interacting with our application and their requests fails.

Our application isn't under very high load. We set the maximum connection of our database to 1000. And the peak number of connection is around 35 (sum of all instance's connections). I checked the stats of Database and it seems pretty happy i.e CPU utilization almost never goes above 50%, Disk is 30% used, Memory usage is around 50%.

I can provide more details if needed. Would appreciate any help!

Comment: A couple of thoughts: is your deployment in the same region as your database? Does restarting the proxy help?

Comment: @enocom The database is at `us-central1-f` but the deployments are in various regions i.e `us-central1-{a, b, f}` and I just checked and the `us-central1-f` deployments have the same issue.

Proxy restarts automatically when it fails the readiness check or when it timesout. I also forced a restart be editing its YAML and the error occur with 1-2 hour span.

Comment: This seems like a networking issue and debugging it could be tough. Are you running a service mesh? Have you tried reproducing the error on a fresh cluster?

Comment: @enocom Service Mesh.. I don't know anything about that. I think we are not using it.

We did create a fresh cluster. I don't remember whether we really faced the error there.

At this moment, I completed all the preliminary work to move us to using database using private IP (also setup a private DNS) with SSL and using the direct db connection on one instance we haven't got the operational error.